# Where can I change the background color of the notification in the Info header?

Tags: customization, theme

I'm using a [theme](http://studiollb.wordpress.com/download/), but I can't find the settings of this message which is almost unreadable. In the User Preferences / Theme / Info-tab  are only a few colors to configure. I also searched in the User Interface settings for something like 'Error Message', but I couldn't find anything. Is there any way to change the color of this GUI component?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To my knowledge it cannot be changed, it is defined by the *Box* group in the *User Interface* tab. The only bits of it I could change were the border color and the gradient. The text color is changed globally it seems.

One workaround you could use is to tick the shaded check box and set both values to 100, this gives a bright white which might help against a darker color.

***Default***
[image]

***Brighter***
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately you cannot change that background. It's one of the few colors you can't change.

However, you can change the text color in the Info category:
[image: Header Text Color via Theme > Info]

Comment: @JonathanWilliamson Thank you, it is the Header-Text that must be changed, the same is used for the info "v2.65|Verts..." therefore the other workaround works better for me.+1